# System.out.println("Hi"+6+10); prints Hi610?

Tags: java

Why does it do this? So confuuuusing.

Comment: Because it's converting the integers to string. This is simply the way java string concatenation works.
What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I guess I assumed (stupidly) order of operations based on parameter type.

Comment: Devoted, *your assumption was not at all stupid*. The difference (and application) of the order of operations vs. operator precedence is something that can trip up even veteran developers. Great question by the way.

Comment: As Sean says, the assumption was not at all stupid. It's not at all intuitive sometimes. I presented the explanation as "simple", because the rules are few in number and easy to understand once you know them. But simple does not mean obvious, or sensible. As Sean says, even veteran developers do get tripped up on this pretty easily. So don't beat yourself up over it. Great question. (+1)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Operator precedence and associativity.

Two points:

- Operator `+` does string concatenation if one or both arguments are Strings.
- Operator `+` works from left to right.

So in your example, `"Hi"+6` is `"Hi6"`, and `"Hi6"+10` is `"Hi610"`.

EDIT: As you say in a comment to another answer: If the numbers are first, then a numeric addition is done first, because the leftmost two operands are numbers. Then, only at the end, a string concatenation occurs. So that yields `"16Hi"`.

Comment: +1 - operator precedence / associativity is the key to why you get "Hi610" (rather than "Hi16" which is what the OP apparently expects.)

Comment: Also: If you want `Hi16`, try `System.out.println("Hi"+(6+10));`

Answer (score 3):

Its just a matter of precedence. `"Hi"+6+10` resolves to `("Hi"+6)+10`. Since `"Hi"+6` is then concatenated as a string `"Hi6"`, to which `10` is again concatenated to get `"Hi610"`

To achieve what you are expecting just specify the precedence correctly using braces:

```
System.out.println("Hi" + (6 + 10));
```

Answer (score 2):

The "6" and the "10" are being coerced into strings.

Do you want "Hi 16"? In that case try `System.out.println(“Hi ” + (6+10));`

Comment: so then System.out.println(6+10+"Hi") would print 16Hi?

Comment: Do you really need to ask that? Run it and find out! :)

Comment: Java would try to convert "Hi" to an integer. Not sure what the result will be. As @epascarello says, best is to try it.

Comment: This answer misses the point.  See @Platinum's answer for the real explanation.  It also explains why `System.out.println(6+10+"Hi")` prints `16Hi`.

Comment: @LarryK - incorrect.  It would print 16Hi.  Evaluate left to right.  The '+' operator means String concatenation if **either** operand is a String.  In this case, the left operand (16) is converted to a String.

Comment: @Stephen C: Thank you for the correction. SO doesn't let me edit the comment.

Answer (score 2):

By order of operations, this is equivalent to `System.out.println(("Hi"+6)+10)`. At this point, the rules of Java state that to add "Hi" and 6 you convert both operands to string and concatenate, yielding `System.out.println("Hi6" + 10)`, where "Hi6" + 10 are added according to concatenation again to give `System.out.println("Hi610")`, which will print `Hi610` to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's converting the integers to string. This is simply the way java string concatenation works.

There is [extensive documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) on this subject. You may want to read it.

If you do 6+10+"Hi", you'd get 16Hi out. If you want to add the integers, use parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

6 and 10 are being taken as int which are converted to String by using +. So, you are printing: string+int(tostring)+int(tostring)

http://ideone.com/a3vuH

You expected something else?

Answer (score 0):

You have run into the single overloaded operator in Java - `+` - and the rules for when it means what (string concatenation or addition) are not immediately obvious but very well defined.

As always when the precedence rules are non-intuitive, use parenthesis:

```
System.out.println("Hi " + (6+10));
```